# Cartesian product proof question

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I need to prove that if $A,B,C,D$ are sets,
$(A \times B) \cap (C \times D)=(A \times D) \cap (C \times B)$

I am trying to show that if for all $x,y$ in LHS, it is also an element of RHS.

$(x,y) \in (A \times B) \cap (C \times D) \iff$ $(x,y) \in (A \times B)$ and $(x,y) \in (C \times D)$

$\iff x \in A, y \in B$ and $x \in C, y \in D$

$\iff x \in A, y \in D$ and $x \in C, y \in B$

(Am I allowed to change the order of $y$ as above?) and if so, what law allows me to do that?.

Comment: You are only using associativity and commutativity of the conjunction. That's ok.

Comment: Not a duplicate, the linked article used set intersections in the right-hand side, not additional Cartesian products.

Comment: @CrusoJames  Make sure to accept kholli's answer; it's the same answer I gave but kholli beat me to it by 20 seconds! :)

Comment: Thank you all to you guys. Helped me heaps! I want to accept both of you guys but feel so bad I cannot. Thank you guys!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, because you could write it as

$(x,y) \in (A\times B)$ and $(x,y)\in (C\times D)$

$\iff x\in A\cap C$ and $y\in B\cap D$

$\iff x\in A$ and $x\in C$ and $y\in B$ and $y\in D$

$\iff (x,y)\in A\times D$ and $(x,y)\in C\times B$

$\iff (x,y)\in (A\times D) \cap (C\times B)$

Basically, replacing your commas with 'and,' the reason of the interchange should be clear.

Comment: Well, that looks familiar! =)

Comment: @Bram28: I think our posts were about 18 seconds apart. :P

Comment: Yeah, you beat me to it! :P

Answer (score 2):

Here is what you can do:

$(x,y) \in (A \times B) \cap (C \times D) \iff$

$(x,y) \in (A \times B)$ and $(x,y) \in (C \times D) \iff $

$x \in A \ \color{red}{ and } \ y \in B$ and $x \in C \ \color{red}{ and } \ y \in D \iff $ (by pure logic)

$x \in A \ \color{red}{ and } \ y \in D$ and $x \in C \ \color{red}{ and } \ y \in B \iff $

$(x,y) \in (A \times D)$ and $(x,y) \in (C \times B) \iff $

$(x,y) \in (A \times D) \cap (C \times B)$